# How to choose the right installation procedure for Ansible?

Tags: python, pip, ansible, installation

When one wants to install Ansible, they have different options: [Installing Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html).

Let's imagine I have a fresh CentOS 7 VM with updates installed. As of now, I can choose to install using:

1. The system's package manager:

```
  $ sudo yum install ansible
```

2. Python's package manager:

```
  $ pip install --user ansible
```

or

```
  $ sudo pip install ansible
```

3. Python's package manager in a virtual environment:

```
  $ python -m virtualenv ansible

  $ source ansible/bin/activate

  $ pip install ansible
```

4. Git by cloning the source code from the repository:

```
  git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git
```

Considering I don't really understand what having a virtual environment entails yet,

- Can someone describe the practical differences between the listed methods?
- Which one is the "best" way of installing Ansible?
- In what context would each of the listed methods be more suitable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Installing python packages via `yum` is generally discouraged unless there is some sort of native dependency.  There are no benefits to installing using `yum` over `pip`.
2. We typically recommend staying away from using the global package manager to install packages.  The only exceptions we typically make are for truly global packages (pip, wheel, setuptools, cloud provider cli, virtualenv).  We also use this method when setting up docker environments because docker is limited to single app configurations.  We typically stay away from this method because relying on the OS-provided pythons can be fickle.  As an example, CentOS 6 came with a very old version of python that could not be upgraded, so you had to compile and build python from sources.  This method also does not work if you have multiple apps that need to run from the same server but have different python version requirements.
3. Using a virtual environment is almost always the right choice and should be the default choice.  It isolates your projects' dependencies from other projects that might reside on the same virtual machine or computer.  The key word here is isolation.  You can isolate particular versions of libraries and python that are specific to particular applications and have them run side-by-side on the same instance.
4. pip install from git when you need a specific hotfix or feature that has not yet been released to pypi.

Comment: Thanks man! I'll look into venv, then. Too bad Ansible documentation doesn't really tell you this.